# bash if clause with and or combined

Tags: bash, if-statement, clause

I'm trying to be smart but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me to do this a bit simpler?

```
if [[  "${DATUM}" == "${today}" &&  "${STUNDE}" == "${HH24}" ]] || [[  "${DATUM}" == "${today}" &&  "${STUNDE}" == "20" ]] || 
[[  "${DATUM}" == "${today}" &&  "${STUNDE}" == "" && "20" == "${HH24}"  ]]; then
```

Is there a way to combine it?

Comment: Try to nest your `if-statements`

Comment: You have `(Cond1 AND Cond2) OR (Cond1 AND Cond3) OR (Cond1 AND Cond4 AND Cond5)` which can be simplified to `Cond1 AND (Cond2 OR Cond3 OR (Cond4 AND Cond5))`

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be translated to:

```
(C1 and C2) or (C1 and C3) or (C1 and C4 and C5)
```

Applying boolean arithmetics you can simplify it as:

```
C1 and (C2 or C3 or (C4 and C5))
```

This said, you can add a nested if statement to, first, check the C1 condition and, second, check the other conditions. It does not simplify the code a lot but here it is:

```
if [ "${DATUM}" = "${today}" ]; then
    if [ "${STUNDE}" = "${HH24}" ] || [ "${STUNDE}" = "20" ] || { [ "${STUNDE}" = "" ] && [ "${HH24}" = "20" ]; }; then       
        # Insert the code to execute when the conditions are satisfied
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your boolean expression can be simplified applying the [law of distributivity of conjunction (⋀, *, AND) over disjunction (⋁, +, OR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Monotone_laws):

```
(a ⋀ b) ⋁ (a ⋀ c) = a ⋀ (b ⋁ c)
```

But to simplify it further, note you can, in `bash`, use `&&` and `||` inside the (`bash`-specific) `[[ .. ]]` command:

```
[[ $a == 1 && $b == 2 ]]
```

Also, when using `[[ .. ]]` compound command (over POSIX `[ .. ]`) you don't have to quote variables. And to test for null-strings, you can use the shorter `-z $var` form over `$var == ""`.

All this together yields:

```
if [[ $DATUM == $today ]] && [[ $STUNDE == $HH24 || $STUNDE == 20 || -z $STUNDE && $HH24 == 20 ]]; then
    # ...
fi
```

To further simplify it, we would need to have more details on your application logic, possible values, etc.